# Failover mechanism for JMS consumer microservice is down

Tags: spring-boot, jms, activemq-classic, failover, consumer

We are using activemq for micro services message broker. My query is about how to build failover mechanism for consumer service. If the consumer service is down , how to proceed further. Can we do somethign like hystrix or any other failover/circuit breaker mechanism for such scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is 'yes'. The details on how to implement depend on your use case. Recommended architecture:

1. Publish to virtual topic

Option A: Multi-threaded consumers
2. Multiple competing consumers reading from the queue that is used as the subscriber from the virtual topic

Option B: Single-threaded HA consumers
2. Multiple competing consumers reading from the queue that is used as the subscriber from the virtual topic using an exclusive consumer to ensure only one thread is processing data and the other consumers are hot-standby